# Observable.Zip when number of sequences to zip is unknown until runtime

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observable

I need to model an approval process. Before it was pretty simple. Two roles had to approve something, and then we could go on to the next step:

```
public class Approved
{
    public string ApproverRole;
}

var approvals = Subscribe<Approved>();

var vpOfFinance = approvals.Where(e => e.ApproverRole == "Finance VP");
var vpOfSales = approvals.Where(e => e.ApproverRole == "Sales VP");

var approvedByAll = vpOfFinance.Zip(vpOfSales, Tuple.Create);

approvedByAll.Subscribe(_ => SomeInterestingBusinessProcess());
```

But now there is a new requirement: the number of roles required to approve something can vary:

```
public class ApprovalRequested
{
    public string[] Roles;
}
var approvalRequest = Subscribe<ApprovalRequested>().Take(1);
var approvals = Subscribe<Approved>();

var approvedByAll = ???;

approvedByAll.Subscribe(_ => SomeInterestingBusinessProcess());
```

I feel like I am missing something pretty obvious here... can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Edit**

To clarify: The approval process is on a per item basis. The order that the approvals can arrive in is undefined. We don't care if one role approves an item multiple times.

Comment: The `Zip` operator expects things in pairs to stay in step. What you're doing here could have multiple approvals by the Finance VP without the Sales VP and things could get out of sync. You need to define your requirements here better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can essentially be reduced to creating a `Set` from a stream of values where values may be out of order or many in nature.

If N is the cardinality of the set, we can trivially assume that the process will not proceed until at least N types of values (roles in this case) have been pushed.

Here's a sample solution of the Zip operator; perhaps this can get you started:

```
    public static IObservable<IList<T>> Zip<T>(this IList<IObservable<T>> observables)
    {
        return Observable.Create<IList<T>>(observer =>
        {
            List<List<T>> store = new List<List<T>>(Enumerable.Range(1, observables.Count).Select(_ => new List<T>()));

            return new CompositeDisposable(observables.Select((o, i) => 
                o.Subscribe(value =>
                {
                    lock (store)
                    {
                        store[i].Add(value);

                        if (store.All(list => list.Count > 0))
                        {
                            observer.OnNext(store.Select(list => list[0]).ToList());
                            store.ForEach(list => list.RemoveAt(0));
                        }
                    }
                }))
            );
        });
    }
```

Test:

```
        Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))
                  .GroupBy(i => i % 3)
                  .Select(gr => gr.AsObservable())
                  .Buffer(3)                      
                  .SelectMany(set => set.Zip())
                  .Subscribe(v => Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", v)));
```

One issue here is that you may lose out on the initial values while the groups are being formed, so you might want to incorporate that by rewriting the method as `IObservable<IList<T>> Zip<TKey, T>(this IGroupedObservable<TKey, T> observables)`.

Comment: I am unable to find this Zip overload. I am running Rx 2.0.20823 off of nuget including Rx-Experimental.

Comment: @JoãoBragança I've added a Zip method which gives you a basic idea of a set.

Comment: The following overload exist in Rx v2.0:

    static IObservable<IList<TSource>> Zip<TSource>(this IEnumerable<IObservable<TSource>> sources)

Answer (score 2):

In the current version of Rx (which I got from NuGet), there is a version of `Zip()` that takes a collection of observables and returns an observable of collections. With that, you can do something like this:

```
string[] requiredApprovals = …;

var approvedByAll = requiredApprovals
    .Select(required => approvals.Where(a => a.ApproverRole == required))
    .Zip();

approvedByAll.Subscribe(_ => SomeInterestingBusinessProcess());
```

But as @Enigmativity pointed out, this will work only if you can be sure that each person approves in the same order and that all items will eventually be approved by all required roles. If not, you will need something more complicated than just a `Zip()`.

Comment: Please see my comment to Asti's answer.

Comment: I have no idea why could that be. I am using 2.0.20823 too and it works fine for me. I don't have Rx-Experimental, though.

Comment: Ah, I believe it is because you are targeting 4.5 and I am still on 4.0. Do you ave any insight as to why it is not included?

Comment: I thought about that too, but it works for me when targeting .Net 4.0 too (both from VS 2012 and 2010).

Comment: I need to pay more attention. Zip takes IEnumerable<IObservable<T>>, I needed something for IObservable<IObservable<T>>

Comment: Why? The code you showed has `string[] Roles` and you can build `IEnumerable<IObservable<T>>` the way I showed. Besides, `IO<IO<T>>` doesn't make much sense to me here.